# Crosswalk messages after forum conversion

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am crosswalking 1,200 url's using mod_rewrite and a php script.

Q: Is there a way to do the same without the php script ?

I migrated a forum from YaBB (Perl) to SMF (php). The migration caused a changed in urls that external links come in on.  I have 1,200 numbers that are cross-walked.  Example of 5 of them for sake of discussion

```
old_id      new_id
1135287707   1
1135313823   2
1135313961   3
1135314073   4
1135314194   5
```

The [301] translation that I want `mod_rewrite` to do is as follows

```
old: www.host.com/widgets/forum/YaBB.pl?num=<old_id>
new: www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=<new_id>
```

I wasn't sure how or if possible to have mod_rewrite use a cross-walk table directly.  At present I am using two steps, a rewrite to run a script.

The .htaccess is in the "forum" directory

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" "num="
 RewriteRule "YaBB\.pl"       "redirect.php"
```

The rewrite effect is

```
from: www.host.com/widgets/forum/YaBB.pl?num=<old_id>
  to: www.host.com/widgets/forum/redirect.php?num=<old_id>
```

which runs the redirect script. The script has the crosswalk data in an array and looks like:

```
  <?php

  if (!array_key_exists('num', $_GET)) {
          header('Location: https://www.host.com/widgets/forum');  // no number, goto main page
          return;
  }

  // got a number, check it for cross-walk

  $crosswalk = [
        1135287707 => 1,
        1135313823 => 2,
        1135313961 => 3,
        1135314073 => 4,
        1135314194 => 5,
        ... 1200 more ...
  ];

  $num = $_GET['num'];

  if (array_key_exists($num, $crosswalk)) {
        $new_id = crosswalk[$num];
        header("Location: https://www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=$new_id", 301);  // redirect to new url
  }
  else {
        header('Location: https://www.host.com/widgets/forum'); // no crosswalk, goto main page
  }

  ?>
```

Are there other more efficient crosswalk mechanisms ?

Answer (score 0):

What we do on our servers is create RewriteRules and put it into .htaccess, it might not be the cleanest solution, but it is handled all by apache. You probably want to create  simple script to generate the rules and then put them into .htaccess in root of your web.

The list will then look something like

```
RewriteRule ^widgets/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=1135287707$ http://www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^widgets/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=1135313823$ http://www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^widgets/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=1135313961$ http://www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=3 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^widgets/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=1135314073$ http://www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=4 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^widgets/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num=1135314194$ http://www.host.com/widgets/forum/?topic=5 [R=301,L]
```

You would want to also end it with redirection if nothing matches

```
RewriteRule ^widgets/forum/YaBB\.pl\?num= http://www.host.com/widgets/forum [R=301,L]
```